# Need to query a Collection attribute that has @IgnoreLoad annotation

Tags: google-app-engine, collections, objectify

I have a LinkedHashSet<> attribute in my entity that I don't want to load when the entity is retrieved.  However, I do need to query against it.

When I tried to construct the *IN* clause inside the **filter()** method from the Query class, it requires a Collection as the 2nd parameter.  Since the LinkedHashSet attribute is not loaded, the query doesn't work.  Is there another way that I can query the LinkedHashSet<> attribute or I have to build out a separate entity (which I really hate to do).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to query has nothing to do with what is loaded in your entity. Queries operate on indexes in the datastore. Putting @IgnoreLoad on a field does not affect what is in the datastore. However, if you load and then subsequently *save* an entity with that annotation, you will wipe out the indexed data in the datastore.